# Scrolling through a Stack of Images using Mousemove and Left button click

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to make my own PACS viewer to scroll through a series of CT head images.

Problem is, I am having trouble scrolling through all 59 images. I can get it to scroll through from the first to the 59th image, but I am unable to get it to scroll back to the beginning, if you keep the LMB click and move the MOUSE UP.

Right now when you LEFT CLICK and MOUSE DOWN you scroll only from image 1 to 59 and when you LEFT CLICK and MOUSE UP it doesn't scroll back to the first image.  Any help?

jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var lbDown = false;

    $("#imgs").mousedown(function(e) {
        if (e.which === 1) {
            lbDown = true;
        }
    });
    $("#imgs").mouseup(function(e) {
        if(e.which === 1) {
            lbDown = false;
        }
    });

    $("#imgs").mousemove(function(e) {
        if(lbDown) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).find('img:visible').next().show();
        }
    });
});
```

I made a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/C4Y6H/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/finulu/3/edit)**

```
$(function() {
    var $imgs = $('#imgs'),       // Cache your elements
        $img = $('img', $imgs),   // Cache your elements
        lbDown = false,
        Y = 0,                    // Get mouse Y coord
        exY = 0;                  // Used to store old Y value and compare with
                                  // new one to get the direction.

    $imgs.on("mousedown mouseup",function(e) {
        if (e.which === 1) {
            e.preventDefault();
            lbDown = e.type=="mousedown";  // Boolean true/false
        }
    }).on("mousemove", function(e) {
        if(lbDown) {           
           e.preventDefault();
           Y = e.clientY;                              // Get new value
           var $visible = $(this).find('img:visible'); // Get the visible one
           $img.not(":first").hide();                  // Hide all (but first)
           $visible[Y>exY ? "next" : "prev"]().show(); // Ternary Operator
           exY = Y;                                    // Remember old value
        }
    });
   // You might also want to add mouseleave and set lbDown to false.
});
```

You code needed the fix to also hide overlapping images in order to see the previous one (on mouse left move).

---

A slightly different approach would be also to get the .eq() image by calculating the

```
(mousemoveCoordY - clickedInitiallyAtY) % numberOfImages
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/finulu/5/edit)**

`%` (Reminder Operator) will create an infinite loop, just a faster mousemove might skip some frames*.

```
$(function() {
    var $imgs = $('#imgs'),
        $img = $('img', $imgs),
        n = $img.length,
        lbDown = false,
        Y = 0,
        clickedY = 0;

    $imgs.on("mousedown mouseup",function(e) {
        if (e.which === 1) {
            clickedY = e.clientY;
            e.preventDefault();
            lbDown = e.type=="mousedown";
        }
    }).on("mousemove", function(e) {
        if(lbDown) {           
            e.preventDefault();          
            $img.hide().eq((e.clientY-clickedY)%n).show();
        }
    });
    // You might also want to add mouseleave and set lbDown to false.
});
```

---

*The math (I was talking about) to make it run slower  would be something like:

```
 $img.hide().eq((((e.clientY-clickedY)*0.3)|0)%n).show();
```

**[LIKE IN THIS DEMO](http://jsbin.com/finulu/6/edit)** where (0.1 - 0.9) is the sensitivity (multiplier) you need.

Comment: That is awesome.. except it only scrolls in the horizontal mouse moving direction, when it should scroll in the Y axis, not the X axis.  much appreciated

Comment: @bobafart hahaha yes I know I was fixing my answer.

Comment: that is utterly amazing.  I changed it to the Y direction on JS Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/C4Y6H/1/

Comment: @bobafart if you want to a slightly different approach (with infinite loop): http://jsbin.com/finulu/4/edit

Answer (score -1):

On every move you show the next (in)visible image. There is no code to hide previous images, hence do the thing in reverse. Maybe checking for a direction on Y could be a starter... and If Y > or < image.height/2, direction is -1 or 1, then change your next to previous...

Comment: thank you for your comment.  this is the part i cannot conceptually understand.  why use image.height?  how do I actually show the previous image?  there is no such thing as .previous().show() so how is it done?  thanks

Comment: Not sure why the -1, oh well... Best way would be to store images in an array and cycle through the array. Make a ratio of the nb of images / height of image so for X pixels you show image x..

Comment: @Eric good idea, also using a sprite image would increase performance. In that case an even simpler approach of only moving the background-position....